# How to implement mqtt client in a desktop application without revealing mqtt details

Tags: security, client, mqtt

I am making a desktop application (python) which can communicate to an android app, both using mqtt clients. I want to know how to secure or hide my mqtt details (username, password, ip , port) from anyone who goes on looking the desktop application.

Currently I am having mqtt server details (username, password, IP, port) in a config.ini file which is exposed to anyone who wants to look. I considered encrypting config file, or hardcoding details in code itself and converting code to exe or obfuscating it. But searching through all the information on internet, it seems if a person seriously tries, the obfuscating or packaging of code can be reverse engineered easily and any excryption is not safe as again, the encrytion key can be obtained from reverse engineered code too.

A way which was suggested in different links for a different (but similar) scenario was to not include details on client side at all but keeping them on server side and fetching them via API call. I can do that too. But I am not sure it will serve the purpose, as if someone can read through code, he can also call that API and get mqtt details.

So how to handle this? If API based securing can be done then how to go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are approaching this from the wrong end.  You cannot secure a desktop application if anyone can access the files on it!

You or someone on the security team needs to have control of the MQTT broker.  The UserIds and Passwords should be the end-user's credentials that they input when they start the desktop application (and not the ones allocated by you).

Finally, you need to be using SSL/TLS certificate so that the user credentials flow encrypted between the desktop application and the MQTT broker.

If you do the above then having the IP address and Port # in a configuration file is not a problem because you have secured the MQTT broker and using SSL/TLS to encrypt the user credentials.

Your approach to security first is good, you are just working from the wrong end.

Comment: That makes sense. This will indeed work to secure access from an unwanted out of the system hacker. But still here the end user himself can mess with the system if he wishes to as he does have his creds. Can we have some approach to avoid that too?

Comment: I think you need to do some reading on MQTT security.  Do searches on MQTT broker permissions i.e. ACL (Access Control List).   You can setup permissions on UserIds to limit what they can and cannot do.

Comment: right, chked that, I got a rough idea how to use it to prevent my stated scenario in my use case. Need to play around it a bit more to reach exact solution. Thanks :)